# Change format for string as date in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I get my date as a string from the controller in the format "20150627", where 2015 is year, 06 is month and 27 is the day. I want to show in the format 2015/06/27 or 06-27-2015 or in any date readable form. I cant change the codes in controller so need to do this in the view side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not best way but simple way is

```
.Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(x => x.ColumnName).ClientTemplate("#= ColumnName.substring(0,4) + '/' + ColumnName.substring(4,6) + '/' + ColumnName.substring(6,8) #")
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Palani for your help, but it deesnot seem to work... I think I need to modify the clientTemplate part a bit more (not just columnName).

Comment: I solved using, ' columns.Bound(p => p.NDCInfo.last_change_date).ClientTemplate("#= NDCInfo.last_change_date.substring(0,4) #" + "\\-" + "#= NDCInfo.last_change_date.substring(4,6) #" + "\\-" + "#= NDCInfo.last_change_date.substring(6,8) #");'